# WP8 get Grid (content panel) height in run time

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I have a basic question. I have my MainPage.xaml code like this,

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" 
                       Margin="9,-7,0,0"  Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" Foreground="Black" />
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" >

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

In my MainPage.xaml.cs file,

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MessageBox.Show(ContentPanel.Height.ToString());
        }
```

My message box returns `NaN` value but I would like to get a specific value rather than indefinite value.

Thanks.

Comment: use      void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ContentPanel.ActualHeight.ToString());
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestions,

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(DisplayMessage);
        }

void DisplayMessage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ContentPanel.ActualHeight.ToString());
        }
```

This returns me height of my content panel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you should check the actual height of your content panel in the Loaded event. In the constructor it will be NaN because the actual values are not yet determined...

Comment: Quite right but- ActualHeight will be 0 in Constructor after InitializeComponent(). Height is NaN (Not a Number) because Grid Height is set to Auto. But you are right that checking ActualHeight in Loaded event is what OP is probably looking for.